# Masking credit card number using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and I need to mask credit card numbers present in a Spark's Dataframe where the last four digits are only shown. How to do that ?

Below is my table

```
    +----------+------------+
    |first_name|        card|
    +----------+------------+
    |       abc|999999999999|
    |       lmn|222222222222|
    +----------+------------+
```

Expected output:

```
    +----------+------------+
    |first_name|        card|
    +----------+------------+
    |       abc|********9999|
    |       lmn|********2222|
    +----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pyspark you can also use the substring function

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
tst= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("name1",9999999999),("name2",2222222222)],schema=['name','number'])
# This is assuming your card number is not a string. If not skip this cast
tst_cast = tst.withColumn("number_string",F.col('number').cast(StringType()))
tst_mask = tst_cast.withColumn("masked_number",F.concat(F.lit('******'),F.substring(F.col("number_string"),6,4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Seq("123456789").toDF()
.select(concat(lit("********"),regexp_extract('value',".{4}$",0)).as("card"))
.show()

+------------+
|        card|
+------------+
|********6789|
+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

another alternative -

```scala
  df.withColumn("masked_cc", expr("concat(translate(left(card, length(card)-4), '0123456789', '**********')," +
      "right(card, 4))"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----------+------------+------------+
      * |first_name|card        |masked_cc   |
      * +----------+------------+------------+
      * |abc       |999999999999|********9999|
      * |lmn       |222222222222|********2222|
      * +----------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use substring and lpad together to generate a similar behavior,

```
df.selectExpr("lpad(substring(card,length(card)-4,4),16,'*') as card").show()

+----------------+
|            card|
+----------------+
|************9999|
+----------------+
```